# Display blob image in MYSQL with ASP/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, odbc

i need to display an image stored in mysql db as a blob field using ODBC connection in ASP page with C#. Please help me

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="stdImg" %>
```

using System;
using System.Web;

public class stdImg : IHttpHandler
{

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{


    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection con = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sis"].ConnectionString;


    con.Open();
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PHOTOGRAPH FROM student_mast WHERE ADMISSION_NO='1000000001'";


    byte[] buf = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();


    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(buf);
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Connection string like this

```
<add name="MYSQLConnectionString" connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};database=DB;option=0;pwd=pwd;port=3306;server=yourserver;uid=user;sslverify=0"
   providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

First Install the ODBC driver for MYSQl

here is download link

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html

**Update**
use data grid and make connection to DB and in data grid use this code

```
 <asp:TemplateColumn  HeaderText="Image">
         <ItemTemplate >
            <img runat="server" 
                 src='<%# "getImage.aspx?ID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 
                 "ImageIdentity")  %>' ID="Img1"/>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

verify your image field name

Comment: I have installed it and all other connections are working fine. I want to know How to display a blob image in asp page

Comment: Please Show Clearly which version of asp  u r using ? Is this asp.net or asp

Comment: Its ASP.net with VS 2008 i added the code i am working on above

Comment: Thank You very much All for the help. I resolved the problem :)